# How to take an output list of a function as input to another function in Haskell?

Tags: function, loops, haskell

Let's say that we have a function `truthtable ::BoolExpr -> [([Variable], Bool)]` that returns the value in List of ordered pairs of the variable and it's Bool evaluation.

functions are defined as following

```
module BoolExpr (Variable, BoolExpr(..), evaluate) where
import Data.List
import System.IO

type Variable = Char
data BoolExpr = T
 |F
 |Var Variable
 |Not BoolExpr
 |And BoolExpr BoolExpr
 |Or BoolExpr BoolExpr
 deriving(Show)


-- evaluates an expression
evaluate :: BoolExpr -> [Variable] -> Bool
evaluate T _            = True
evaluate F _            = False
evaluate (Var v) vs     = v `elem` vs
evaluate (Not e) vs     = not (evaluate e vs)
evaluate (And e1 e2) vs = evaluate e1 vs && evaluate e2 vs
evaluate (Or  e1 e2) vs = evaluate e1 vs || evaluate e2 vs

--remove duplicates
rmdups :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
rmdups = map head . group . sort


variables :: BoolExpr -> [Variable]
variables T = []
variables F = []
variables (Var e1) = [e1]
variables (And e1 e2) =rmdups$ sort $ variables e1 ++ variables e2
variables (Or e1 e2) =rmdups$ sort $ variables e1 ++ variables e2
variables (Not e) = variables e



 --function to get the subsets of a list
subsets :: [Variable] -> [[Variable]]
subsets [] = [[]]
subsets (x:xs) = [zs | ys <- subsets xs, zs <- [ys, (x:ys)]]
```

Now the function subsets return all possible subsets in a string 
eg.

```
> subsets "abc"
["","c","b","bc","a","ac","ab","abc"]
```

Now how to take each element in this list and put it here

`evaluate (And (Var 'a') (Or (Var 'c') (Var 'b'))) "HERE"`

I know how to do something like this in C using iteration over the list and doing the calculation.

My approach : ***number of subsets of string= 2^n***, where n is the number of elements

now I would use a scenario like this:

```
let x=0
iterate form x to (n-1) (subsets $ variables (And e1 e2)) !! x
```

i know that `!!` operator allow to pick element from the list according to the index written.
Finally the result of the chunk above is applied to the `evaluate` function at the end part HERE. that what the function `truthtable` evaluate as a whole

```
> truthtable (And (Var 'a') (Or (Var 'c') (Var 'b')))

[("",False),("c",False),("b",False),("bc",False),("a",False),("ac",True),("ab",True),("abc",True)]
```

any ideas how to apply this in Haskell

Answer (score 4):

> Now how to take each element in this list and put it here
>
> ```
> evaluate (And (Var 'a') (Or (Var 'c') (Var 'b'))) "HERE"
> ```

Like this:

```
map (evaluate (And ...)) (subsets "abc")
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> > truthtable (And (Var 'a') (Or (Var 'c') (Var 'b')))
>
> [("",False),("c",False),("b",False), ...
> ```

You mean,

```
truthtable expr =
            [ evaluate expr s | s <- subsets (variables expr) ]
{-
 expr ::               BoolExpr
 variables ::          BoolExpr -> [Variable]
 variables expr ::                 [Variable]
 subsets ::                        [Variable] -> [[Variable]]
 subsets (variables expr) ::                     [[Variable]]
 s ::                                             [Variable]
 evaluate ::           BoolExpr                -> [Variable]  ->  Bool
 evaluate              expr                       s           ::  Bool
[evaluate              expr                       s         ] :: [Bool]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
truthtable ::          BoolExpr                               -> [Bool]
-}
```

The `[ foo | x <- xs ]` syntax is known as *"list comprehension"*.

It is *analogous* to a *loop* in imperative paradigm, and can be read as *"the list of `foo`s, for `x` in `xs`".* It is also equivalent to `map (\ x -> foo ) xs`; also

```
  [ foo | x <- [a, b, c] ]
=
  [ foo | x <- [a]   ++              [b]   ++              [c] ]
=
  [ foo | x <- [a] ] ++ [ foo | x <- [b] ] ++ [ foo | x <- [c] ]
=
  [ foo | let x=a  ] ++ [ foo | let x=b  ] ++ [ foo | let x=c  ]
```

`::` means *"has type"*.